# Is the concept "numerology" based on Hindu Scriptures?In particular which Texts give the rules of how to relate the Navagrahas with the numbers?

Tags: scripture, navagraha, numerology

The order of the Navagrahas is as follows:

> Aditya/Surya(Sun)
> Soma/Chandra(Moon)
> Angaraka/Mangal/Kuja(Mars)
>  Budha(Mercury)
>  Brihaspati(Jupiter)
>  Sukra(Venus)
>  Sani(Saturn)
> Rahu and Ketu.

This order can be found in [Vyasa Krutha Navagraha Stotram](http://dilip-raut.blogspot.in/2013/07/nava-graha-stotra-by-sage-veda-vyasa.html) and similar [stotrams](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Nava_Graha_Stotram_II) and even in the following small [prayer](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Nava_Graha_Prarthana) dedicated to them :

> Soorya souryamadendhurucha padaveem , sanmangalam mangala,¬ Sad budhim
>   cha budho Guruscha kurutham Shukra sukham , sam sani,¬ Rahur bahu
>   balam karothu vipulam Kethukulasyonnathim,¬ Nithyam preethikara
>   bhavanthu bhavatham sarve prasanna Graha
>
> Let **sun** give me courage , **Moon** give high position , **Mars** grant
>   auspiciousness,¬ Let **mercury** give good brain , Let **Jupiter** give great
>   numbers , **Venus** give pleasure ,**Sani** peace, **Rahu** give me physical strength and
>   **Kethu** greatness of our family,¬ And let all the planets be pleased
>   with me and start liking me.¬

So,the most natural way of associating the nine numbers 1,2..to..9 with the Navagrahas is this:

Sun-1,Moon-2,Mars-3,Mercury-4,Jupiter-5,Venus-6,Saturn-7,Rahu-8 and Ketu-9.

But those who are familiar with the subject of [Numerology](http://www.sanatansociety.org/vedic_astrology_and_numerology/indian_numerology_1.htm#.WH8wubnldoc) will know that this is not quite the order that is followed .

In numerology they follow this:

**Sun-1,Moon-2,Jupiter-3,Rahu-4,Mercury-5,Venus-6,Ketu-7,Saturn-8,Mars-9.**

So,quite different from the association given further above.

**My Questions-**

Which Hindu Scriptures give these rules of Numerology  and in particular the rules regarding which number is to be associated with which of the Navagrahas?

Comment: Is Numerology Indian/Hindu work? What is the sanskrit name for Numerology?

Comment: @TheDestroyer I don't know if numerology is mentioned in Scriptures..That's y i asked this question..You can chk the link i gave in the Q itself..They are using the term Vedic Numerology..but of course that does not prove anything..as for ur 2nd Q, Sankhya Tattva or [Sankhya Sastra](http://www.astrojyoti.com/sankhyasastranumber3.htm) may be

Comment: @Rickross - May be you are talking about "JanmaAnka Shastra" OR Mulanka Shastra  i.e.जन्मांक शास्त्र & मूलांक शास्त्र.They are associeated with astrology.I will try to find more , but not sure about whether could Provide sources , We find this type of information generally in Joytisha books.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Yes u are right ..Jyotisha texts are the place to look into..

Comment: Numerology is not a part of scripture. There was a study of it, and because it is old it is called 'vedic', but its not part of scripture. Just because a work has the word shastra as part of it doesn't mean its scripture.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda How can u be so sure?If u know then u shud post an answer..BTW where did u find the word Shastra in my question?

Comment: The reference to Shastra was in the comments above not in the question. Not posting an answer because you cannot prove a negative, you can only prove a positive - I cannot prove there are no references to numerology, you can only prove there are references to numerology.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Why can't u prove the negative?Suppose u read a scholarly article which says so..U can post that as an answer..Also the shastra i mentioned in comments only in reply to a question..and i also said there "may be".. that means i was not even sure if such terminology is used in scriptures..In any case "is numerology  mentioned in hIndu scriptures?" is a perfectly valid question..I don't think that it deserves a downvote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all this answer does not address the main question which is about  Navagraha's relation with the numbers,nor the one which asks about the basis of numerology in Hindu Scriptures.

It only indicates how the relation  may have been formed using the [Katapayadi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katapayadi_system) system.

And also it indicates that numerology is not quite out of place in hInduism as we can see from this article :   [Aksharasamkhya Nirdesha(@Kamakotimandali.org)](https://www.kamakotimandali.com/srividya/aksharasamkhya.html)

> ambA is worshipped through various mantras. Of these, panchadashI,
>   shuddha ShoDashI, saubhAgya brahmavidyA or saubhAgya panchadashI
>   (ShoDashI) and mahAShoDashI are the most important mantras in most of
>   the dAkShiNAtya shrIvidyA sampradAyas. The number of letters in these
>   mantras is indicated by the names of parAmbA based on katapaya
>   calculations.
>
> Name 1: lalitAmbA
>
> La-3; li-3; tAm-6; bA-3 Total: 3+3+6+3 = 15 -> shuddha panchadashI
>
> Name 2: lalitAmbikA
>
> La-3; li-3; tAm-6; bi-3; kA-1 Total: 3+3+6+3+1= 16 -> shuddha ShoDashI
>
> Name 3: shrIlalitAmbikA
>
> shrI-2; La-3; li-3; tAm-6; bi-3; kA-1 Total: 2+3+3+6+3+1= 18 ->
>   saubhAgya brahmavidyA
>
> Name 4: shrIrAjarAjeshvarI
>
> shrI-2; rA-2; ja-8; rA-2; je-8; shva-4; rI-2 Total: 2+2+8+2+8+4+2 = 28
>   -> mahAShoDashI
>
> The same can be seen with respect to chaNDI as well. chan-6 and DI-3,
>   thus indicating 6+3=9. On reversing the digits, the mantra denotes the
>   thirty-six tattvas starting from shiva till dharA.